# Sybase : Updating a table with Top keyword

Tags: sql, sybase

```
Update 
  Table1 
set 
  name = (select top 1 a.col 
          from Table2 a 
          where Table1.num = a.num)
```

This seems to work in Sql Server but get an error message in Sybase saying `Incorrect syntax near keyword 'top'`.

Can some one find out what's the problem?

Comment: You want the Top first answer but you don't define an order in the subquery. Does that mean any row will be ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET name = 
    ( SELECT MIN(a.col) 
      FROM Table2 a 
      WHERE Table1.num = a.num
    )
```